# DOM manipulation is slow in angular while using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I was developing an Angular app, in my dashboard.comp.ts I need to implement jquery event (**due to other reason I have used jquery**), jquery event working properly with my typescript objects. Now problem is when I click through jquery, DOM manipulation getting delay, so that, output getting delay like: 5/7 seconds.

**dashboard.comp.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import SensorServices from '../Services/Settings/SensorServices';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: '../Views/Dashboard.html',
    providers: [SensorServices]
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    public sensor: any;
    constructor(private _sensorServices: SensorServices )
    {

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {

        this._sensorServices.getAll({})
            .subscribe((result) => {
                var self=this;
                $(document).on('click', '.sensorSizeInDesign', function (e) {
                    self.sensor=result;
                });
            });
    }
}
```

**html**
N.B: the given html is fewer basically element generated from server side, so there are multiple sensors. here is an example.

```
<div class='sensorSizeInDesign' data-sensorId="123"></div>
<h3>{{sensor.Port}}</h3>
```

**For each click event Port getting delay to be changed.**

Comment: you should not use jQuery inside angular applications. Make use of `@ViewChild` for DOM accessing instead; https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: Consider this a sign from above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution: just updating my jquery code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this._sensorServices.getAll({})
        .subscribe((result) => {
            var self=this;
             $('.sensorSizeInDesign').click(function(e){
                self.sensor=result;
             })
        });
}
```

Comment: as i recommended in my answer you should try to get rid of jquery - and you can also get rid of `var self = this` using this implementation: `$('.sensorSizeInDesign').click(() => {
                this.sensor=result;
             })`

Comment: Ok  @messerbill , Sure.

Answer (score 1):

avoid using `jQuery` inside `angular` applications. Therefor `@ViewChild` exists:

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Your click handler should be implemented this way:

```
function onClick() {
  this._sensorServices.getAll({}).subscribe((result) => {
    this.sensor=result;
  })
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='sensorSizeInDesign' (click)="onClick()" data-sensorId="123"></div>
<h3>{{sensor.Port}}</h3>
```

Comment: i can't implement function onClick() inside .ts file

Comment: @sebu sure you can - why not?

Comment: let me try using @ViewChild

Comment: why ViewChild, what is wrong with doing what this guy suggested ? why are you trying to bypass Angular and run straight to the DOM ? it doesn't bite.

Comment: @Stavm no it does not bite, that's true but it is simply a lot of cleaner. Angular makes use of `ViewChild` and lifecycle methods, so there is really no need of using `jQuery` on top - and it is also recommended not to do this. Thats why I think you should not use jquery in angular so far there is no REAL need to do so - i can imagine that `performance` issues may also occur

Comment: @messerbill Check my answer, just updated my jquery code, but i'll try with  ViewChild

Comment: @messerbill my comment was directed to the comment before it, not to your answer which I plus one'd. using ViewChild directly, for such simple things as string interpolation is not required. as shown by the snippet in this answer - this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

ngOnInit(): void {

```
    this._sensorServices.getAll({})
        .subscribe((result) => {
            var self=this;
            $( window ).on( "load", function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.sensorSizeInDesign', function (e) {
                self.sensor=result;
            });
            });
        });
```

Try that